# how to collapse/compress/reduce string columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Essentially, what I am trying to do is join Table_A to Table_B using a key to do a lookup in Table_B to pull column records for names present in Table_A.

Table_B can be thought of as the master name table that stores various attributes about a name. Table_A represents incoming data with information about a name.

There are two columns that represent a name - a column named '**raw_name**' and a column named '**real_name**'. The '**raw_name**' has the string "code_" before the **real_name**.

i.e.

```
raw_name = CE993_VincentHanna

real_name = VincentHanna
```

Key = real_name, which exists in Table_A and Table_B

Please see the mySQL tables and query here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65e13/1

For all **real_names** in Table_A that DO-NOT exist in Table_B I want to store **raw_name**/**real_name** pairs into an object so I can send an alert to the data-entry staff for manual insertion.

For all **real_names** in Table_A that DO exist in Table_B, which means we know about this name and can add the new **raw_name** associated with this **real_name** into our master Table_B

In mySQL, this is easy to do as you can see in my sqlfidde example. I join on real_name and I compress/collapse the result by groupby **a.real_name** since I don't care if there are multiple records in Table_B for the same real_name.

All I want is to pull the attributes (stats1, stats2, stats3) so I can assign them to the newly discovered raw_name.

In the mySQL query result I can then separate the NULL records to be sent for manual data-entry and automatically insert the remaining records into Table_B.

Now, I am trying to do the same in Pandas but am stuck at the point of groupby on **real-name**.

```
e = {'raw_name': pd.Series(['AW103_Waingro', 'CE993_VincentHanna', 'EES43_NeilMcCauley', 'SME16_ChrisShiherlis',
                          'MEC14_MichaelCheritto', 'OTP23_RogerVanZant', 'MDU232_AlanMarciano']),
     'real_name': pd.Series(['Waingro', 'VincentHanna', 'NeilMcCauley', 'ChrisShiherlis', 'MichaelCheritto', 
                           'RogerVanZant', 'AlanMarciano'])}

f = {'raw_name': pd.Series(['SME893_VincentHanna', 'TVA405_VincentHanna', 'MET783_NeilMcCauley', 
                            'CE321_NeilMcCauley', 'CIN453_NeilMcCauley', 'NIPS16_ChrisShiherlis',
                            'ALTW12_MichaelCheritto', 'NSP42_MichaelCheritto', 'CONS23_RogerVanZant',
                            'WAUE34_RogerVanZant']),
     'real_name': pd.Series(['VincentHanna', 'VincentHanna', 'NeilMcCauley', 'NeilMcCauley', 'NeilMcCauley',
                             'ChrisShiherlis', 'MichaelCheritto', 'MichaelCheritto', 'RogerVanZant',
                             'RogerVanZant']),
     'stats1': pd.Series(['meh1', 'meh1', 'yo1', 'yo1', 'yo1', 'hello1', 'bye1', 'bye1', 'namaste1',
                          'namaste1']),
     'stats2': pd.Series(['meh2', 'meh2', 'yo2', 'yo2', 'yo2', 'hello2', 'bye2', 'bye2', 'namaste2',
                          'namaste2']),
     'stats3': pd.Series(['meh3', 'meh3', 'yo3', 'yo3', 'yo3', 'hello3', 'bye3', 'bye3', 'namaste3',
                          'namaste3'])}

df_e = pd.DataFrame(e)
df_f = pd.DataFrame(f)

df_new = pd.merge(df_e, df_f, how='left', on='real_name', suffixes=['_left', '_right'])

df_new_grouped = df_new.groupby(df_new['raw_name_left'])
```

Now how do I compress/collapse the groups in df_new_grouped on real-name like I did in mySQL.

Once I have an object with the collapsed results I can slice the dataframe to report real_names we don't have a record of (NULL values) and those that we already know and can store the newly discovered raw_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop duplicates based on columns `raw_name_left` and also remove the `raw_name_right` column using `drop`

```
In [99]: df_new.drop_duplicates('raw_name_left').drop('raw_name_right', 1)
Out[99]:
            raw_name_left        real_name    stats1    stats2    stats3
0           AW103_Waingro          Waingro       NaN       NaN       NaN
1      CE993_VincentHanna     VincentHanna      meh1      meh2      meh3
3      EES43_NeilMcCauley     NeilMcCauley       yo1       yo2       yo3
6    SME16_ChrisShiherlis   ChrisShiherlis    hello1    hello2    hello3
7   MEC14_MichaelCheritto  MichaelCheritto      bye1      bye2      bye3
9      OTP23_RogerVanZant     RogerVanZant  namaste1  namaste2  namaste3
11    MDU232_AlanMarciano     AlanMarciano       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be thorough, this can also be done using Groupby, which I found on Wes McKinney's blog although drop_duplicates is cleaner and more efficient.

http://wesmckinney.com/blog/filtering-out-duplicate-dataframe-rows/

```
>index = [gp_keys[0] for gp_keys in df_new_grouped.groups.values()]
>unique_df = df_new.reindex(index)
>unique_df
```